# How to align items justified in android linear layout horizontal orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have 5 images which should be placed horizontally in a linear layout and should be in a justified manner with the 3rd image at the center of the screen. All the images are of same width and height.

ie the padding between the images should dynamically adjust.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to use a Relative layout in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

android:layout_weight="1"

for each of your items which will solve your problem and arrange the items using equal space in the screen

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff5678" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff5678" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff5678" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff5678" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff5678" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Beetwen each `ImageView` add empty `View` with params: `android:layout_width="0dp"`
`android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JustifyLayout](https://github.com/ahmadmuzakki29/justify-layout) to align center and add the same margin among the child.

Like this one:

[image]